# Embed clipping path to jpg file without photoshop

Tags: c++, image-processing

I want to embed(save) a clipping path to jpg file, and i will see clipping path when i open jpg file in photoshop. (See attachment file).

I want to find some libraries to do it.(ex: Image magick, but i'm not sure Image Magick can do it)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l67rP.jpg

Thank all

Answer (score -1):

To do clipping path, Photoshop is best the best software. With pen tool of Photoshop one can easily draw lines around edges of sharp edges object. Every line and curve also point of clipping path editable also one can reposition points of clipping path. It is advisable to avoid pen tool for soft edged objects like fur, hair, blurred edged.
 One thing worth mentionable is that one has to invest some time to be adept on pen tool and in the in the future it will worthy investment.

Comment: Thank Shamim. But my program running on server without photoshop. I need solution can implement by c++ or c# programming.